# Poor encoding of a file retrieved via FTP

Tags: php, linux

When I get a CSV file, the header is bad. What impact the elements key

Exemple:

**File format in FTP Server:**

```
"store","id"
"admin","2"
"user","3"
....
```

Content Data geted from FTP Server by PHP

```
array(
    ['"store"'] => admin,
    ['id'] => 2
)
array(
    ['"store"'] => user,
    ['id'] => 3
)
```

Normally I have to have

```
['store'] and not ['"store"']
```

NB: That is for the first element only AND The encoding file is UTF-8

Comment: Please add the code where you are parsing your file.

Comment: I don't understand... what's your question? Or what doesn't look right with the file?

Comment: use fgetcsv and in argument set "enclosure" double quote.

Comment: I parse my file with the basic code of Magento ( ZF ) its correct 100%

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the documentation for [getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) you need to pass the enclosure argument.

Comment: I parse my file with the basic code of Magento ( ZF ) its correct 100%, i have the probleme only with the first item